# List items changes when scrolling

Tags: android, list, scroll, adapter

I want different layout for item at position 0 and other layout for rest of all items.
but when i scroll list the layout for position 0 i.e (R.layout.list_simple) sets at any random position..

please help me...

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (vi == null) {

        if (position == 0) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_simple, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    // if (data.size() <= 0) {
    // holder.text.setText("No Data");

    // }
    tempValues = (RssFeedStructure) data.get(position);

    if (tempValues.getIconSrc() != null) {
        img.DisplayImage(tempValues.getIconSrc(), holder.image);
    }

    holder.text.setText(tempValues.getHeadLine());
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // Log.e("TEmpImage",""+tempValues.getIconSrc());
    img.DisplayImage(tempValues.getIconSrc(), holder.image);

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView text;
    private ImageView image;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the first view is reused to create the other view. use `getViewTypeCount()`  to tell the adapeter how may item u have and `getItemViewType(int position)` to tell which layout to use. in this way the to layout will not be reused.

```
 @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position==0) ? 0: 1;
        }
```